# go "-buildmode=c-shared" compiled DLL is not working on Windows XP 64 bit target

Tags: go, mingw-w64, cgo

I am using golang to implement go packages, and generate c-shared dlls from same code, to support my Go as well as C applications. I have to support Windows XP, as there are clients using it.

go1.10.8 is used as it is last official go version to support Windows XP.

I have created a add.go file, which has following code:

```
package main

import (
    "C"
)


//export Add
func Add() bool {
    return true
}

func main() {}
```

I compiled for windows/amd64 with following command:
go build -o add.dll -buildmode=c-shared ./add.go

The compilation generates add.dll, which is working fine on windows 7 and higher windows versions. But on Windows XP I am getting error: "runtime: failed to create new OS thread (22)"

In the dependency walker, for add.dll, I am seeing 3 missing functions in kernel32.dll,

- RtlAddFunctionTable
- RtlLookupFunctionEntry
- RtlVirtualUnwind

Surprisingly, when add.go is compiled for 32 bit arch(CC=i686-w64-mingw32-gcc-posix CXX=i686-w64-mingw32-g++-posix GOOS=windows GOARCH=386), it works on Windows XP 32 bit machine. Also does not require above functions in kernel32.dll.

I am new to golang, mingw-w64 and stackoverflow :). I dug this as much as I can and found out that go build command uses mingw-w64 compiler to generate add.dll. And mingw-w64 has stopped supporting Windows XP & 2K3.

I still tried compiling with older versions of mingw-64/tdm-gcc, but observed same error on Windows XP. Also went through: [link](https://github.com/msys2/MINGW-packages/issues/4706), thought this might be the solution, but when I compiled mingw-w64-gcc package with --enable-threads=win95, it gave error "win95 is an unknown thread package".

Has anyone tried this? or any suggestion about how I can make this work for Windows XP 64 bit target machines.

Comment: Where are you even getting a 64-bit version of Windows XP from?  While there were some early builds of XP in 64-bit, it was never really viable - at least as far as desktops shipped by OEMs.  Can you just ship 32-bit binaries for XP?

Comment: Oh wow - there was a 2003 edition of XP Pro for 64-bit and it can be downloaded with a VS/MSDN subscription.  I still don't think anyone actually used it.

Comment: Can't ship 32-bit binaries as the apps loading the DLL will be 64-bit executables. Yes, that's the XP version I am getting error on.

Comment: This is just a guess, but [this article](https://www.fireeye.com/blog/threat-research/2020/03/six-facts-about-address-space-layout-randomization-on-windows.html) mentions "Windows XP and Windows Server 2003 and earlier do not support ASLR", while the [Go 1.16 changelog](https://golang.org/doc/go1.16#linker) mentions that "On Windows, go build -buildmode=c-shared now generates Windows ASLR DLLs by default. ASLR can be disabled with --ldflags=-aslr=false.". Might be worth a try, but I have no idea

Comment: I am using go1.10.8 and I verified that ASLR, DEP flags are OFF in the compiled binary. Thanks for the information though.